# label label-danger, stuck here

Tags: selenium

I need to validate, username & password fields. When incorrect password or username. i want to validate that error message which is displayed

following shows the HTML. class shows label label-danger, but it doesn't work if i use findelement by class, it throws an no element found exception.

```
<div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="loginform-password" class="form-control" type="password" value="ssssssssssss" name="LoginForm[password]">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="label label-danger">Incorrect username or password.</div>
  </div>
  <input id="loginform-type" type="hidden" value="company"name="LoginForm[type]">
  <button class="nd-btn" type="submit">LOGIN</button>
</div>
```

Here's what I tried but failed:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("label label-danger"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Incorrect username or password."));
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEiVF.png)

My code is this

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// To explicitly wait for 10 seconds
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Navigate to Required URL
driver.get("http://ndustrious.com/");
// Maximize the Window
driver.manage().window().maximize();
// To explicitly wait for 5 seconds
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// click on EXECEPTIONAL ORGANIZATIONS
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/site/company-login']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginform-username")).sendKeys("abc");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginform-password")).clear();
    WebElement labelElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'label label-danger']"));
    labelElement.getText();
```

Comment: Please share your code where you call findelement.

Comment: @Mattias Lindberg, I used this, driver.findElement(By.className("label label-danger"));
or driver.findElement(By.linkText("Incorrect username or password."));

Comment: Please update the question title to be a question and more relevant to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`By.className` does not work for several class-attributes, you need to use xpath:

```
WebElement labelElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'label label-danger']"));
```

Your second approach also does not work, because the text is not a text of a link-element but text of a `div`

if you want to print the text:

```
labelElement.getText();
```

Comment: Thank u @drkthng this helped me. But when i try printing that Error message this is what i get in Console window                           `[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (906394ab-3539-4c3d-aa8b-cc24130cedaa)] -> xpath: //div[@class = 'label label-danger']] " `

Comment: how do you try to print it? -> you need to do element.getText()

Comment: This wat i used ` String ErrorMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'label label- danger']")).getAttribute("value");
 System.out.println(" " +ErrorMsg);`

Comment: just use getText() instead of getAttribute("value") -> I even updated my answer -> don't forget to vote up ;-)

Comment: I have updated my code, please go through it & Help me

Comment: if you don't write your results to the console, of course you will not see anything! you're not even saving the result of getText() in a variable. -> you might try System.out.println(labelElement.getText()); But that does only work in certain circumstances, depending on how you are conducting your tests, but try it

Comment: Yeah, u r right. System.out.println also doesnt work. I have updated the code. Just go through it.

Comment: just save it in a variable and then stop the debugger at that position, then you will see, that your desired text is extracted. If you don't know how to log your results, please do some research or ask another question since this has nothing to do with your original problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map get a WebElement by By.classname(), you can pass only only one class. It would be best to call it by

```
driver.findElement(By.className("label-danger"));
```

Comment: Thank u this also works as i mentioned to @drkthng answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Incorrect')]");

Comment: this throws an `NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple CSS class names in a locator, you will need to use a CSS selector.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.label.label-danger")).getText();
```